# HTML\rich text in Drupal's node title?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need the node titles to be able to display some text formatting.

As far as I understand, Drupal's title field is just plain text, it doesn't allow [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) or any other input format. Is that true? Is there a way to override this, or another solution?

I am working with Drupal 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pretty easily do this in your theme, there are different ways to do with. The simplest would probably to do it in your template.php

```
/* this function generates the variables that are available in your node.tpl,
 * you should already have this in your template.php, but if not create it
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    // It's important to run some kind of filter on the title so users can't
    // use fx script tags to inject js or do nasty things.
    $vars['title'] = filter_xss($vars['node']->title);
}
```

What happens in the function is that it overwrites the default value for $title in the node.tpl which holds the variable used for the title. It is usually placed within a h1 or h2 tag, so you should be aware of that. The filter_xss is used to only allow basic html tags, so protect the site, you can look at that function [here](http://d6-api.drupal.org/api/function/filter_xss/6). That are some other filter functions, like check_markup, and filter_xss_admin, but you can give a second param for filter_xss which is an array of allowed tags, so should the default not be good enough, you can just change it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the original question was for Drupal 6, this post still appears in search results 10 years later.

In modern Drupal, it's possible to use some custom code like what some of the other answers here suggest, but they are either incomplete, clunky, or open security vulnerabilities.

Instead, check out [HTML Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/html_title) module

Answer (score 0):

Use function `mytheme_preprocess_page` for `D7`.

Answer (score -1):

Extending the module mentioned by wiifm, for D7 there is now also:  https://drupal.org/project/html_title_trash

It allows more tags and also works for block titles, rather than just node titles.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I disagee. This DOES provide and answer to the question. The question is "I need the node titles to be able to display some text formatting. As far as I understand, Drupal's title field is just plain text, it doesn't allow HTML or any other input format. Is that true? " And the answer is: yes it is true that Drupal core does not allow HTML in node titles, but when you use the module above it does.

Comment: OP says that he is working with Drupal 6 at the end of his post. Also there is a "drupal-6" tag there. And the html title trash module was introduced in Drupal 7. I think your post should have been made as a comment on wiifm's answer. Because it is a nice complement but not a direct answer.